# Global Get Current UserID function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using the MVC4 framework and in a lot of instances throughout the code I want to get the current user ID.

I understand to do this I can use:

```
  [InitializeSimpleMembership]
  public ActionResult SaveTask(FormCollection form)
  {
      var userID = WebSecurity.CurrentUserID;
  }
```

This works Correctly but I find myself having to put the `[InitializeSimpleMembership]` on every `ActionResult`. Ideally I would like a static function which I can call:

```
var userID = Utilities.CurrentUserID;
```

which is in a class called Utilities:

```
   public static Int32 CurrentUserID{

    get
    {
        return WebSecurity.CurrentUserID;

    }

  }
```

Note I know this will fail as `WebSecurity` will need the `InitializeSimpleMembership Attribute` but but I want to show by example what I want to achieve. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `[InitializeSimpleMembership]` to the top of your controller instead of for each action and can use `WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name)`

Or you can use

```
var userId = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name).ProviderUserKey;
```

Comment: Yes I should have copied the default Account one and put it on top if the controller, if there is no other suggestions.

Comment: In one of my projects we do the needed customization on a custom controller and make the other controllers inherit from it.